# spring-kafka consumer group does not list as active

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have `spring-boot-1.5.13` app that uses `spring-kafka`. When the app is up and  actively producing (`KafkaTemplate.send()`)/consuming (`@KafkaMessageListener`), it doesn't list as an active consumer. It shows all the `console-consumer` Active/InActive but never the `consumer_group` that the app is using.

```
/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --new-consumer --list
console-consumer-80187
console-consumer-95926
console-consumer-55164
console-consumer-45212
```

The spring `ConsumerConfig` specifies `group.id`, `auto.commit.enable=true`

Comment: I just tested it with the current release and it works fine; I see the group. Note that, as explained on the [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) all boot 1.5.x users are recommended to upgrade to 1.3.x - boot pulls in a very old version). The current version compatible with boot 1.5 is 1.3.6. Even better, upgrade to boot 2.0 and spring-kafka 2.1.8.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. As per the link you shared `All users with brokers >= 0.10.x.x are recommended to use spring-kafka version 1.3.x or higher due to its simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62`. So it means, underlying `kafka broker version 0.10.1.1` can be supported by `spring-kafka 1.3.6`, even though as per maven central, it is compatible with `kafka broker version 0.11.0.2`. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct - there is a link there to the [Confluent compatibility page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix). Any java client version can be used with 0.10.1.x broker. You should plan, though, to get to a more current broker; there are lots of new features such as headers.

Comment: I would have loved to upgrade the `broker` version, but the `spring boot` compatibility matrix for `spring-kafka` and thus the `kafka-client` version posed a constraint for me to choose a `kafka` broker that is guaranteed to work together with a certain `spring-boot` release. I can't bump up the `spring-boot` version now and hence tied up with a certain `kafka` broker. :(

Comment: I tried using `spring-kafka 1.3.6` with `boot 1.5.13`, but the above issue remained.... however I can see the consumer gets reported through `burrow` even without the upgrade..

Comment: >`I can't bump up the spring-boot version now and hence tied up with a certain kafka broker`. That is incorrect; you can use any broker version, regardless of the kafka-clients version; see the compatibility matrix. I currently use the 1.1.0 broker with Boot 2.0 and 1.5 applications.